# article has no publisher in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Why is there no **publisher** field on the article entry type in biblatex?

I am using biblatex to create my bibliography, however I can't seem to figure out how to reference a publisher in an article Entry Type.

For example:

```
The Golden Ratio: A Contrary Viewpoint
Clement Falbo
The College Mathematics Journal
Vol. 36, No. 2 (Mar., 2005), pp. 123-134 
(article consists of 12 pages)
Published by: Mathematical Association of America
```

How should I include the information about Mathematical Association of America in my entry?

Comment: Journal articles are usually cited without mention of the publisher: I've not come across a style which does this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "missing" publisher field for `@article` is not specific to biblatex, but also a feature of LaTeX's standard bibliography styles (`plain`, `unsrt`, `alpha`, `abbrv`). See for example section 3.1 of [Oren Patashnik, *BibTeXing*](http://bibtexml.sourceforge.net/btxdoc.pdf) for the required, optional, and ignored fields of the different entry types. If you nevertheless want to include the information about the journal's publisher, biblatex offers the `addendum` and `note` fields.

Comment: it is not specific to bibtex, it is specific to the used style file. If it knows a publisher entry then bibtex will handle it like other entries.

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks for pointing out my mistake -- answer corrected.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically transform the content of the publisher field in the case of `@article` to the `addendum` field`?